# Using reCaptcha.MVC always returns false in production

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I am integrating a reCAPTCHA to my site using [ReCAPTCHA MVC](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/Home/Document) it is working fine in my development machine but after deploying to production it always send false response. I followed all the steps correctly that are mentioned in the documentation of [ReCAPTCHA MVC](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/Home/Document). and also configure my website url in domain list of [Google ReCAPTCHA key settings](https://www.google.com/recaptcha).

My form is ajax based so that's i written my code as per MVC AJAX.

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [CaptchaValidator]
        public JsonResult SubmitContact(ContactUs contactus, bool captchaValid)
        {
           if (!captchaValid)
           {
             return Json("Invalid captcha");
           }


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //some impl.
                return Json("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                //some impl.
                return Json("Error");
            }

        }
```

`captchaValid` always false in production but works fine in developement.

I am not found any luck.

Could any one please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved: I am getting always response false due to my requested site's certificate has expired.

Answer (score 0):

May be because you registered localhost on registration. So it works on development and when you try to use same keys on your production, it doesn't!

Comment: please read my question carefully, my implementation working on development but not in production.

Comment: updated my answer, but which domain did you register?

Comment: but i am using deferenct keys.